# dynamic target click event not triggering

Tags: jquery, css

I have multiple, dynamically, created tables. Inside the tables I have text inputs that I want to access later.

I have given each table an id of "divFlipGlobalParams`<?=$property->pID?>`" and every text input has a class of "globalDealParameter"

If I use static id without the PHP, it works fine. However, if I use static id's then I will have multiple id's with the same name which will cause issues.

```
$('#divFlipGlobalParams' + <?=$property->pID?>).on('keyup', '.globalDealParameter', function(e) {
```

I'm trying to think of the proper solution for this

Comment: try with $('[id^=divFlipGlobalParams]')

Comment: @gaetanoM It works on the first instance of "divFlipGlobalParams", but not any others. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you have to do a selector on a unique ID? Even if you're processing after is different you can do a generic selector then extract the ID after to do your processing such as doing a generic selector like:

```
$('.divFlipGlobalParams').on('keyup', function(e) {
  // ... process code
});
```

Adding a class to each link.

Which you can check the console here has all the information you want to do any specific processing:

https://jsfiddle.net/a5omzh2d/1/

Answer (score 0):

Apologies, I made a noob error!

My issue was that because I was adding the jQuery event into the included page which loops, the function was being duplicated also!

I moved the function outside of this and it works fine.

Thanks for everyone's input!